# how to get the FULL details for the current user using UserService, including their default address?

Tags: addressbook, region, country, spartacus-storefront

The default address data returned contains country and region codes, but not country and region names.
Any one know if there's a way to do that in Spartacus, or would that be something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! You can use Spartacus's [configurable endpoint mechanism](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints) to achieve this.

For your particular case, you would want to override the `addressDetail` and `addresses` endpoints. You will need to add the FULL fields for country and regions your endpoints will look like this:

```
    addresses: 'users/${userId}/addresses?fields=DEFAULT,addresses(country(FULL),region(FULL))',
    addressDetail: 'users/${userId}/addresses/${addressId}?fields=country(FULL),region(FULL)',
```

Alternatively, you could just add `fields=FULL` to receive ALL the available details.

Comment: thanks @L Tiger. It worked for me :)